# XAMPP how to retrieve ibdata1 database information

Tags: mysql, database, apache, xampp

Before detect this problem, the notebook has always been hibernating. Suddenly for a mysterious error, the notebook is restarted, after rebooting, whenever I run XAMPP,(Apache working well) this doesn't connect with mysql(it start and just before connect to port, it stop) returns this error:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
[mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
[mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
[mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
[mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
[mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
[mysql]  entire log window on the forums
```

I tried to execute from windows manager the mysql process but it did the same thing, it is started and immediately stopped.

After some research, i tried to remove the ibdata1 file from xampp/mysql/data folder, and ran XAMPP, by this way all work perfectly.

So i think the problem is in the file ibdata1 but i need some information stored in the file, there's a program or method to copy some information or something else to repair to this problem ?

Comment: You'll probably do better asking on [dba.se] but make sure you have the MySQL error logs and any relevant events from the Windows event viewer available before you post there.

Comment: Thanks to your advice I found another possible cause, in particular in files inside table's folder, with extensions ".frm" and ".ibd".
There's any program which can open and modify these files ?